# Speeding up an SQL query selection from a large table of integers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `numbers` that looks like this

```
id (int) | start (int u) | end (int u)
1          50              100
2          250             396
3          900             1000
```

It has about 400k rows and the data in it never changes.
The ranges do not overlap.

I am running a query like this against it:

```
SELECT id FROM numbers WHERE *somenumber* BETWEEN start AND end LIMIT 1
```

The query takes about .3s to finish which is an eternity, so I tried to come up with some solutions to make it faster.
The only thing I came up with, was slapping some indexes on the start and end columns, but doing so actually made it SLOWER, the same query now amazingly takes .9s to finish with INDEXES present on the two columns.

So, how can I make this query faster if at all possible?

Comment: Did you created 2 index - 1 on each column or 1 multi-column index?

Comment: Separate index for each column.

Comment: Can you try removing both and creating multi column index on start and end?

Comment: Nice, that made it about one third faster.

Comment: Happy to help...:)

Comment: As well as the index, try OPTIMIZE TABLE to make sure the statistics are accurate.

Answer (score 0):

First try an index on `numbers(start)`.

If that doesn't help (and the `between` can impede things), then let me assume that the ranges don't overlap.  If not, then try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM numbers
WHERE *somenumber* >= start 
ORDER BY start DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If the ranges *do* overlap, then you have a bigger issue.  I would recommend creating a new table with non-overlapping ranges.

Comment: I tried it and but it is only about 6% faster. The order by kills the speed.

Comment: The `order by` should be using the index.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an multi-index on column `start` and column `end` will speed up the process for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

REVISED...

After re-thinking, it can even be simplified further down to

Lets extrapolate on your sample data even in the condition that the Id numbers are not in exact sequential order

```
id (int) | start (int u) | end (int u)
1          50              100
2          250             396
3          900             1000
4          101             175
5          418             724
6          397             417
7          176             249
```

Say you are looking for number 723 (now in record #5).

```
 SELECT N.*
       FROM numbers N 
       WHERE N.start <= 723 
         AND N.End >= 723
         AND N.start < 723
```

The between is the same as the explicit >= and <=, but by also adding that the start MUST be less than the number you want, you are eliminating all those higher from any consideration.  it forces the list to the lowest qualifier.